# Linux - find the path of g++ lib

Tags: c++, linux, path, linker, g++

I installed these two libraries: glut and curl.

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev
```

when I have to compile a program I use:

```
g++ -o executable file11.cpp file2.cpp -lglut -lcurl
```

and it works!

How can I know where the linker search for "-lglut" or "-lcurl"?

"-lsomething" correspond to a path, How can I find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker will look in directories specified by the `-L` option and in standard system directories, which are usually `/lib` and `/usr/lib`.  Although you're not using any `-L` options GCC will usually pass some to the linker so it can find GCC's own libraries (e.g. the C++ standard library) unless you use `-nostdlib`.  GCC will also add `-L` options for the contents of the `LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

To see the options GCC passes to the linker you can compile with `-v` (for verbose) and to see which libraries the linker uses you can pass `-Wl,--trace` to GCC, which causes it to pass `--trace` to the linker, which makes it output something like:

```
/usr/bin/ld: mode elf_x86_64
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../lib64/crt1.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../lib64/crti.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/crtbegin.o
/tmp/ccJHrbSx.o
-lglut (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../lib64/libglut.so)
-lcurl (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../lib64/libcurl.so)
-lgcc_s (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/libgcc_s.so)
/lib64/libc.so.6
(/usr/lib64/libc_nonshared.a)elf-init.oS
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
-lgcc_s (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/libgcc_s.so)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/crtend.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
```

This shows the libraries that were found for the `-lglut` and `lcurl` libs on my system.  The libs are found in that path because on my system GCC passed `-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../lib64` to the linker (shown by compiling with `-v`)

You can canonicalize those paths using `readlink`

```
$ readlink -f /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../lib64/
/usr/lib64/
```

Answer (score 2):

It checks `/lib`, `/usr/lib`, and any paths passed to `-L`.

Answer (score 0):

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html
It just turns the string into a filename, and checks normal locations for it, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ldd /path/to/your/executable
```

Comment: That tells you where the run-time linker finds the required libraries, which is not necessarily the same as where they were found at link-time

Comment: @JonathanWakely Looking at the post it seems that (1) no flags were passed to the linker indicating location of libraries, and (2) the compiled program is being executed on the same system without specifying `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  In which case, `ldd` would pretty much result in the same set of libs as those used for the *compilation*.

Comment: Not necessarily. The contents of `$LD_RUN_PATH` at link-time and the contents of `ld.so.conf` at run-time can both affect it too.  So although `ldd` is _probably_ useful, it's not always going to show the same as the libs found at link-time.  As I said, it's not necessarily the same.

Comment: Or slightly more correctly, it's affected by the contents of the dynamic linker cache at run-time, which is affected by the contents of `/etc/ld.so.conf` when the cache was last rebuilt.